# CSS styles "leaking" to non-intended elements, why does it happen and how to prevent it?

Tags: css, css-selectors

According to the W3Schools CSS notes, if you use an ID on an element, then the CSS styles defined for that ID (using #id_name) should only apply to that element, and this is how you should style an element which only appears once.

I've a site which includes a display table (of actual tabular data, it's a grid of phone numbers in different classifications).  So I've placed the table inside a div and set the div to have an ID.  I then defined styles for the ID in the stylesheep.

HTML:

```
<div id='phone_number_grid'>
    <table>
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#phone_number_grid table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
#phone_number_grid th,td {
   border: 1px solid #000040;
   background-color: #ccccff;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

The style works perfectly on the table it's intended for, but it is also affecting a completely different table which has no class or id settings, and is contained in a completely unrelated div with it's own (completely unrelated) class settings, on a different page that uses the same stylesheep.

How do I stop the #phone_number_grid styles from affecting unrelated tables?

Note I previously tried the same thing using a class ID on the div, with the same results - the styles "leaked" onto other tables that didn't mention them.

Q1: Why are these styles applying themselves to elements that don't reference them?

Q2: Is there a CSS way of saying "do not apply any styles at all to this specific element"?

Comment: Don't trust w3schools!

Comment: Are you saying that your styles are actually (wait for it...) cascading?

Comment: Stylesheep?  I know it's a typo, but that's BAA-D!

Comment: I used to DJ in a Goth club of called "Black Sheep". 
The CSS file genuinely is called stylesheep.css.  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second style extends to all td elements, instead of just those belong to table #phone_number. Update as per below.

```
#phone_number_grid table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
#phone_number_grid th, #phone_number_grid td {
   border: 1px solid #000040;
   background-color: #ccccff;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Elie - that's solved it.  All becomes clear.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`#phone_number_grid th,td` affects all `#phone_number_grid th` and all `td`, not only all `#phone_number_grid th` and all `#phone_number_grid td`.

So write in your selector:

`#phone_number_grid th, #phone_number_grid td`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with this line:

```
#phone_number_grid th,td {
```

CSS selectors separated by commas aren't actually read like you'd first expect. They're two separate selectors, so you're actually matching `#phone_number_grid th` *and* all `td` elements.

You need to be a little more explicit:

```
#phone_number_grid th,
#phone_number_grid td {
    ...
}
```

Putting the selector on its own line may make it easier to see as well.

Answer (score 0):

tYou don't have to define it as a table.

```
#phone_number_grid table{
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
#phone_number_grid th, #phone_number_grid td {
   border: 1px solid #000040;
   background-color: #ccccff;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: this is wrong. look at his html. it should affect `#phone_number_grid table`, not `#phone_number_grid`.

Comment: Aha - interesting, I didn't realise that would work.  Thanks!